# CPP preprocessor to C preprocessor conversion question

Tags: c++, c, preprocessor

*edit: Title probably should be "Preprocessor, CPP compiler to C compiler conversion question. As I have been made aware, the preprocessors are the same. I looks to me like the issue is then that the result of the preprocessed code being compiled, CPP is happier with the layout compared to the C compiler.*

Any advice on how I can make this compatible into a C preprocessor? I was trying to make a slick way of creating a flexible switch statement for a state machine that gets called on occasion and advances when specific criteria are met. Once it gets to the end of the switch statement it signals the state machine has completed by returning true. I wanted to be able to **swap/insert steps without having to re-assign case values**, so this is what I came up with in CPP, which works really well.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

#define DYNCOUNT(start) (__COUNTER__-start)

#define DYNAMIC_SWITCH_BEGIN(identifier,switchElement) \
    const unsigned int identifier = __COUNTER__; \
    switch(switchElement){ \
        case 0:

#define DYNAMIC_SWITCH_ELM(identifier) \
    break; \
    case DYNCOUNT(identifier):

#define DYNAMIC_SWITCH_END \
    break; \
    };


bool stateMachine(unsigned int & state) {

    DYNAMIC_SWITCH_BEGIN(ident, state)
        std::cout << "A" << std::endl;
    //if(some_condition){
    state++;
    //}
    DYNAMIC_SWITCH_ELM(ident)
        std::cout << "B" << std::endl;
    //if(some_condition){
    state++;
    //}

    DYNAMIC_SWITCH_ELM(ident)
        std::cout << "C" << std::endl;
    //if(some_condition){
    state++;
    //}

    DYNAMIC_SWITCH_ELM(ident)
        std::cout << "D" << std::endl;
    //if(some_condition){
    state++;
    //}

    DYNAMIC_SWITCH_ELM(ident)
        std::cout << "E" << std::endl;
    //if(some_condition){
    state++;
    //}

    DYNAMIC_SWITCH_ELM(ident)
        std::cout << "F" << std::endl;
    //if(some_condition){
    state++;
    //}

    DYNAMIC_SWITCH_ELM(ident)
        std::cout << "G" << std::endl;
    //if(some_condition){
    state++;
    //}
    break;
        default:
            return true;
            DYNAMIC_SWITCH_END

                return false;
                //Visual Studios gets confused with the layout and structures it with this tabulation. 
}

int main() {

    unsigned int machineState=0;
    while(!stateMachine(machineState)){/*other operations*/}

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(5));
    return 0;
}
```

However when I try to run it in a C environment through MPLAB I get:

> stateMachines.c:28:9: error: case label does not reduce to an integer constant
>            DYNAMIC_SWITCH_ELM(ident)

So it appears that the CPP preprocessor is willing to interpret a const unsigned int value into its commands while the C preprocessor, or at least MPLAB's C preprocessor, does not.

My only alternative is to trim out some of the content of the DYNAMIC_SWITCH_BEGIN call and instead place a

```
#define ident __COUNT__
```

at the beginning of the switch. Which works too, but I was trying to get a more enforced structure layout.

Comment: Both languages use the same preprocessor?

Comment: I'm not sure, I don't personally know enough about it to say, however in my particular case i'm going to say, probably not, since I am trying to move from Visual Studios Microsoft compiler, over to MPLAB's custom compiler.

Comment: 1. C++ and C use the same preprocessor (rules). 2. `through MPLAB I get:` XC compilers has a long list of known, unfixable bugs. Toss that PIC18 to the trash and move to stm32. 3. It really looks like you are redesigning [protothreads](http://dunkels.com/adam/pt/) [pt](https://github.com/zserge/pt).

Comment: It isn't a preprocessor issue.  `case (__COUNTER__-ident)` is not being evaluated as a constant by the C parser, while it is with the C++ parser.

Comment: LOL, I wouldn't mind tossing a PIC in the trash, but unfortunately(actually fortunately) i'm not the hardware designer.

Comment: Why don't you declare some `enum` ?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm I get that that is the issue, what I am looking for is a convenient correction that doesn't significantly change the structure, but also works between both environments.

Comment: You could rewrite this using Boost.PP library, but it *would* significantly change the structure.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, I'm avoiding enums because I had the personal goal of finding a way that I could re-arrange and insert steps with a cut and paste and not have to re-name elements in other locations, or re-assign case values. Just trying to find a lazy way to make sure the code doesn't accidentally get a bug due to consistency checking errors.

Comment: You can delete `const unsigned int identifier = …` from `DYNAMIC_SWITCH_BEGIN` and change the switch to `switch (switchElement __COUNTER__-1)`, and change its `case 0:` to `case __COUNTER__:`. Then the case in `DYNAMIC_SWITCH_ELM` would be `case __COUNTER__:`. In other words, move the arithmetic that C does not like from the case labels to the switch expression.

Comment: Ah, yes! @EricPostpischil that does the trick. I did change that formula slightly but what you suggest does the job in both C and CPP and is much cleaner looking. I had to do switch(switcheElement+(__COUNTER__+1)) though. I'll post my code below.

Answer (score 0):

Credit to @EricPostpischil for leading me to this solution. The switch will behave as if it starts at 0 even though the case values are adjusting. Since it is behind the scenes it doesn't really matter that the case value doesn't start with 0.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

#define DYNCOUNT(start) (__COUNTER__-start)

#define DYNAMIC_SWITCH_BEGIN(switchElement) \
    switch((switchElement + (__COUNTER__+1))){ \
        case __COUNTER__:

#define DYNAMIC_SWITCH_ELM \
    break; \
    case __COUNTER__:

#define DYNAMIC_SWITCH_END \
    break; \
    };


bool stateMachine(unsigned int & state) {

    DYNAMIC_SWITCH_BEGIN(state)
        std::cout << "A" << std::endl;
    //if(some_condition){
    state++;
    //}
    DYNAMIC_SWITCH_ELM
        std::cout << "B" << std::endl;
    //if(some_condition){
    state++;
    //}

    DYNAMIC_SWITCH_ELM
        std::cout << "C" << std::endl;
    //if(some_condition){
    state++;
    //}

    DYNAMIC_SWITCH_ELM
        std::cout << "D" << std::endl;
    //if(some_condition){
    state++;
    //}

    DYNAMIC_SWITCH_ELM
        std::cout << "E" << std::endl;
    //if(some_condition){
    state++;
    //}

    DYNAMIC_SWITCH_ELM
        std::cout << "F" << std::endl;
    //if(some_condition){
    state++;
    //}

    DYNAMIC_SWITCH_ELM
        std::cout << "G" << std::endl;
    //if(some_condition){
    state++;
    //}
    break;
        default:
            return true;
            DYNAMIC_SWITCH_END

                return false;
}

bool stateMachine_2(unsigned int & state) {

    DYNAMIC_SWITCH_BEGIN(state)
        std::cout << "H" << std::endl;
    //if(some_condition){
    state++;
    //}
    DYNAMIC_SWITCH_ELM
        std::cout << "I" << std::endl;
    //if(some_condition){
    state++;
    //}

    DYNAMIC_SWITCH_ELM
        std::cout << "J" << std::endl;
    //if(some_condition){
    state++;
    //}

    DYNAMIC_SWITCH_ELM
        std::cout << "K" << std::endl;
    //if(some_condition){
    state++;
    //}

    DYNAMIC_SWITCH_ELM
        std::cout << "L" << std::endl;
    //if(some_condition){
    state++;
    //}

    DYNAMIC_SWITCH_ELM
        std::cout << "M" << std::endl;
    //if(some_condition){
    state++;
    //}

    DYNAMIC_SWITCH_ELM
        std::cout << "N" << std::endl;
    //if(some_condition){
    state++;
    //}
    break;
        default:
            return true;
            DYNAMIC_SWITCH_END

                return false;
}

int main() {

    unsigned int machineState=0;
    while(!stateMachine(machineState)){}
    machineState = 0;
    while (!stateMachine_2(machineState)) {}

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(5));
    return 0;
}
```

Edit:

For anybody intesrested, I added some additional useful tools to my original code so it could be used for not only a step-wise advancing state machine but also contain loop-backs or jump forwards in case the state machine is more advanced. Still allows to just copy and paste or insert items wherever desired, keeping with the goal.

```
#define DYNAMIC_SWITCH_BEGIN(elementType,switchElement) \
    do{ \
    const elementType DYNAMIC_SWITCH_OFFSET=__COUNTER__+1; \
    elementType * __DYNAMIC_SWITCH_MODIFY_TARGET = & switchElement; \
    int __DYNAMIC_JUMP_FLAG=0; \
    switch((switchElement + DYNAMIC_SWITCH_OFFSET)){ \
        case __COUNTER__:

#define DYNAMIC_SWITCH_ELM \
    break; \
    case __COUNTER__:

#define DYNAMIC_ADV (*__DYNAMIC_SWITCH_MODIFY_TARGET)++;

#define DYNAMIC_SWITCH_DFLT \
    break; \
    default:

#define DYNAMIC_SWITCH_JUMP(jumpTag) \
    __DYNAMIC_JUMP_FLAG=1; \
    goto jumpTag;

#define DYNAMIC_SWITCH_TAGGED_ELM(jumpTag) \
    break; \
    case __COUNTER__: \
    case (__COUNTER__ +1): \
    jumpTag: \
    (*__DYNAMIC_SWITCH_MODIFY_TARGET) = __COUNTER__ - DYNAMIC_SWITCH_OFFSET; \
    if(__DYNAMIC_JUMP_FLAG)break; //Force to exit and complete on next loop for consistency in stepping behavior.

#define DYNAMIC_SWITCH_END \
    break; \
    }; \
    }while(0);

bool stateMachine(unsigned int & state) {

    DYNAMIC_SWITCH_BEGIN(unsigned int, state)
        std::cout << "A" << std::endl;
    //if(some_condition){
    DYNAMIC_ADV
    //}
    DYNAMIC_SWITCH_ELM
        std::cout << "B" << std::endl;
    //if(some_condition){
    DYNAMIC_ADV
    //}

    DYNAMIC_SWITCH_ELM
        std::cout << "C" << std::endl;
    //if(some_condition){
    DYNAMIC_ADV
    //}

    DYNAMIC_SWITCH_ELM
        std::cout << "D" << std::endl;
    //if(some_condition){
    DYNAMIC_ADV
    //}

    DYNAMIC_SWITCH_ELM
        std::cout << "E" << std::endl;
    //if(some_condition){
    DYNAMIC_ADV
    //}

    DYNAMIC_SWITCH_ELM
        std::cout << "F" << std::endl;
    DYNAMIC_SWITCH_JUMP(tag1)
    //if(some_condition){
    DYNAMIC_ADV
    //}

    DYNAMIC_SWITCH_ELM
        std::cout << "G" << std::endl;
    //if(some_condition){
    DYNAMIC_ADV
    //}
    DYNAMIC_SWITCH_TAGGED_ELM(tag1)
        std::cout << "H" << std::endl;
    DYNAMIC_ADV

    DYNAMIC_SWITCH_ELM
        std::cout << "I" << std::endl << std::endl;;
    //if(some_condition){
    DYNAMIC_ADV

    DYNAMIC_SWITCH_DFLT
        return true;
    DYNAMIC_SWITCH_END
        return false;
}
```